# Dynamic Dropdowns based on WooCommerce Categories/Sub-Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, categories

I am trying to create a dynamic group of dropdowns that will encompass WooCommerce's categories and sub-categories. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around on how this can be achieved. I know that woocommerce has the widget which can be a dropdown, but that is not what I am looking for. I have created an example [here](http://simetriastudio.com/C/nav-example/) showing what I am trying to achieve...this example is pulling the cats and sub-cats from a JSON file.

I also created this image to show what I am after... [image: nav example]

I am not looking for code solutions per-say, just trying to understand what I can grab from WooCommerce's API so I can have a starting point. I am not that familiar with WooCommerce's API and what it is capable of achieving, so this is uncharted territory for me.

Anyone have any feedback, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Serge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a explicit code example that use only Wordpress functions and that will output the raw necessary data for all your product categories hierarchically in a multidimensional array. So as you will see, you don't need to be really familiar with WooCommerce API for that, as it's a Wordpress custom taxonomy.

I have hooked this function to output your product categories raw data in archives and product pages *(just for testing purpose)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'get_product_categories_data' );
function get_product_categories_data(){
    $result = array();
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $level1_terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => 0,
    ) );
    foreach($level1_terms as $term1){
        $level2_terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent' => $term1->term_id,
        ) );
        $result[$term1->term_id] = array(
            'id' => $term1->term_id,
            'name' => $term1->name,
            'level' => '1',
            'link' => esc_url( get_term_link( $term1->term_id, $taxonomy ) ),
        );
        if(count($level2_terms) > 0){
            foreach($level2_terms as $term2){
                $level3_terms = get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    'parent' => $term2->term_id,
                ) );
                $result[$term1->term_id]['childs'][$term2->term_id] = array(
                    'id' => $term2->term_id,
                    'name' => $term2->name,
                    'level' => '2',
                    'link' => esc_url( get_term_link( $term2->term_id, $taxonomy ) ),
                );
                if(count($level3_terms) > 0){
                    foreach($level3_terms as $term3){
                        $level4_terms = get_terms( array(
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'hide_empty' => false,
                            'parent' => $term3->term_id,
                        ) );
                        $result[$term1->term_id]['childs'][$term2->term_id]['childs'][$term3->term_id] = array(
                            'id' => $term3->term_id,
                            'name' => $term3->name,
                            'level' => '3',
                            'link' => esc_url( get_term_link( $term3->term_id, $taxonomy ) ),
                        );
                        if(count($level4_terms) > 0){
                            foreach($level4_terms as $term4){
                                $result[$term1->term_id]['childs'][$term2->term_id]['childs'][$term3->term_id]['childs'][$term4->term_id]  = array(
                                    $term4->term_id => array(
                                        'id' => $term4->term_id,
                                        'name' => $term4->name,
                                        'level' => '4',
                                        'link' => esc_url( get_term_link( $term4->term_id, $taxonomy ) ),
                                    )
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>'; // Raw data output (for testing)

    // return $result;
}
```

**Raw output** - You will get on 4 category/subcategories levels, something like in this extract:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => Clothing
            [level] => 1
            [link] => http://www.example.com/clothing/
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [name] => Hoodies
                            [level] => 2
                            [link] => http://www.example.com/clothing/hoodies/
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [36] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 36
                                            [name] => Hood 1
                                            [level] => 3
                                            [link] => http://www.example.com/clothing/hoodies/hood1/
                                            [childs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [85] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 85
                                                            [name] => Sub Hood 1
                                                            [level] => 4
                                                            [link] => http://www.example.com/clothing/hoodies/hood1/sub-hood-1/
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [37] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 37
                                            [name] => Hood 2
                                            [level] => 3
                                            [link] => http://www.example.com/clothing/hoodies/hood2/
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [name] => T-shirts
                            [level] => 2
                            [link] => http://www.example.com/clothing/t-shirts/
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

> Assuming that you will be able to dispatch the necessary data in a JSON formated data array like in your linked live dropdowns example.

Comment: Thank you Loic. Do I need to place your code in the functions file, or can it be in any other file? I tried placing it in the functions file and don't see any output.

Comment: EDIT: I can see the output in the "Shop/Products" page but not in the other pages...Any particular reason why?

Comment: @Sergio The hook that i am using for the function (woocommerce_before_main_content) is only triggered in product archives pages and single product pages. That's why. Is just for testing and gettig the raw output.

Comment: Got it... so to display globally I can use a different function that is available globally in the site...correct? Btw, this is working perfectly.

Comment: @Sergio yes you are right… It can be used anywhere in Wordpress or WooCommerce. You can build a custom function and then you can call it anywhere (globally).

Comment: One thing I noticed is, in level 4 it will only display one category meaning: (L1) NIKE > (L2)SHOES > (L3)MENS > (L4)WHITE // BLACK this example will only display BLACK and omit WHITE.

Comment: @Sergio I have updated the code in the 4th foreach loop adding missing `[$term4->term_id] `… Try it. It will work now.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you again.